# Dynamically add texture to ColorCube java3d

Tags: java, textures, java-3d

I am very new to java 3D and I would like to add a texture to a `ColorCube()`. I have found this page:

http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/java3d/how-to-apply-a-texture-image-to-a-cube.html

However I can't get it to work, I am not sure how to implement it in my code:

```
 protected BranchGroup createCube() {
        BranchGroup bg = new BranchGroup();
        bg.setCapability(BranchGroup.ALLOW_DETACH);
        bg.addChild(new com.sun.j3d.utils.geometry.ColorCube());
        bg.setUserData("Cube");
        return bg;
    }
```

Finally is it possible to change this texture dynamically?

Like pressing a button or uploading a new texture and change it dynamically?

It is a very wide questions, however I am very new to this.

Comment: See if this can help: http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/java3d/how-a-texture-image-can-be-dynamically-rotated-at-ru.html

Comment: You can call getAppearance().setTexture(Texture) on your ColorCube but a simple com.sun.j3d.utils.geometry.Box would be enough and it would allow you to set a different texture on each face. I advise you to look at the Java documentation of this API. The latest (April 23rd 2015) version of Java3D is the version 1.6.0-pre12, we haven't published the documentation yet but it has the same public API than Java3D 1.5.0, you can use it in the meantime: http://download.java.net/media/java3d/javadoc/1.5.0/index.html